# Do AJAX requests effect page views?

Tags: jquery, ajax, pageviews

Because webfont distributors base their licensing off of page views, would AJAX requests (`.load()`) have an effect?

Example:

```
$('#read').load('index.php #read'); // update #read div
$('#watch').load('index.php #watch'); // update #watch div
```

Comment: It depends on how you use .load, and how the page views are being tracked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, no.

An ajax page request gets a string of information (usually html/xml/json).  For the purposes of the webfont service, it is tracking requests for the webfont itself.  Whenever the browser processes the  tag with the request to the webfont itself, then that is the request that is logged.

Unless, of course, if the ajax request is specifically for the webfont, or an injection of a  element that requests the webfont.  Then yes, it would be a page view for that font.

Answer (score 2):

No, because the whole page is not loading again.  I don't think the font producers are concerned with the ajax paradigm.

Comment: If it's being tracked by javascript, and the javascript is executed again, it would track another pageview. If it's tracked by loading the font and loading another page with ajax results in re-loading the font, then another pageview could be tracked there as well.

Comment: It actually depends if the JS being used to load the fonts in, is being reloaded. If the JS for the font is being reloaded, then it increases the view count. If the JS isn't being reloaded, then no view count increase.

Comment: Web fonts are loaded by way of CSS.  If there's any related javascript it's just to manipulate the CSS.  On the other end, a font producer only has to track how many times the "outline" file, in whatever format, is pulled down by a client.  There would be no need or real value in tracking such a number on the client side.

Comment: Thank you all for the information you have provided. I really appreciate it.